# Home Assistant OS + Wireguard Client addon = IP Masquerading not working correctly

Tags: networking, vpn, alpine-linux

I installed addon wireguard-client on my Home Assistant OS on Raspberry Pi

IP masquerading is not working; I cannot access other devices on my local area network
traceroute stops at `10.10.1.2` instead of going to `192.168.8.169` after

I used to run a wireguard client on debian. Since installing Home Assistant I am trying to reproduce my wg config

here is my original config that worked

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.1.2/24
PrivateKey = redacted
ListenPort = 51820
DNS = 192.168.8.1
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = redacted
Endpoint = mydomain.com:51820
AllowedIPs = 10.10.1.0/24
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

here is the actual config in the plugin

```
[interface]
private_key: redacted
address: 10.10.1.2/24
dns:
  - 192.168.8.1

  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -A FORWARD -p
  tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
post_down: >-
  iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -D FORWARD -p
  tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
mtu: 1420


[peer]
- public_key: redacted
  endpoint: mydomain:51820
  allowed_ips:
    - 10.10.1.0/24
  persistent_keep_alive: "25"
```

I also tried changing the masquerading for the one of my original config replacing `eth0` for `end0` but nothing works

```
post_up: >-
  iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o end0
  -j MASQUERADE
post_down: >-
  iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o end0
  -j MASQUERADE
```

```
ip route list table main default
default via 192.168.8.1 dev end0  src 192.168.8.186  metric 100
10.10.1.0/24 dev wg0 scope link  src 10.10.1.2
172.30.32.0/23 dev hassio scope link  src 172.30.32.1
172.30.232.0/23 dev docker0 scope link  src 172.30.232.1
192.168.8.0/24 dev end0 scope link  src 192.168.8.186  metric 100
```

ipv4 forwarding seems to be enabled

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

```
cat /etc/*-release
3.19.0
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.19.0
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.19"
```